# React Native Firebase .equalTo() with more than one filters

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to use .equalTo() with a list of values?

this is my database structure

```
Posts:{postID(key), posterID, description}
```

Let's say i want to get the records that have postID_A and postID_B. Is there a way to pass a list of keys in the .equalTo() and get all records that match the keys from the list instead of fetching one record then fetch the second one etc?

Comment: What you are asking for is effectively a "logical or" query. Realtime Database doesn't support those.  Making a query for each one separately isn't as expensive as it sounds.

Comment: @DougStevenson where can I find the duplicate?

Comment: Click the link in the yellow box at the top.  It will basically also say "you can't do that", and offer up a solution to a slightly different problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson okay thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> **equalTo()** Return items equal to the specified key or value, depending on the order-by method chosen.

It sounds like what you want to do can be accomplished if you employ these methods (again, all from the documentation):

> you can combine multiple limit or range functions. For example, you can combine the **startAt()** and **endAt()** methods to limit the results to a specified range of values.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data